# notepad++ regular expression mark duplicates strings

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm looking a way to mark the duplicates in the first string  `<item name=".*">`

```
<item name="drawable/ab_solid_dark_holo">
```

in

```
<item name="drawable/ab_solid_dark_holo">@drawable/frameworks_res_ab_solid_dark_holo</item>
<item name="drawable/ab_solid_dark_holo">@drawable/frameworks_res_ab_solid_light_holo</item>
```

Thank you

Comment: i dont quite understand...show expected output

Comment: So sorry for this simple question, i'm just looking regex to mark the first string <item name="drawable/ab_solid_dark_holo">

Comment: @hwnd or any moderators, the question has been identified and answered by Jerry. Please re-edit & if possible re-open this question as i think this would help others. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot highlight *all* the duplicate `<item name=".*">`, but you can highlight almost all; only the last `<item name=".*">` will not get highlighted with this method, because notepad's regex engine cannot support lookbehinds with variable widths.

That regex I'm speaking about is this one:

```
<item name="([^"]+)">(?=[\s\S]*<item name="\1">)
```

It will highlight the `<item name=".*">` only if it is a duplicate, so that if you have:

```
<item name="drawable/ab_solid_dark_holo">@drawable/frameworks_res_ab_solid_dark_holo</item>
<item name="drawable/ab_solid_dark_holo">@drawable/frameworks_res_ab_solid_light_holo</item>
<item name="drawable/ab_solid_dark_holo">@drawable/frameworks_res_ab_solid_bright_holo</item>
<item name="drawable/ab_solid_light_holo">@drawable/frameworks_res_ab_solid_dark_holo</item>
<item name="drawable/ab_solid_bright_holo">@drawable/frameworks_res_ab_solid_light_holo</item>
```

The first two `<item name=".*">` will be marked or highlighted (with find next or it'll get into the results of Find All in Document) but not the last one. You'll unfortunately have to manually find the last one once you know what the duplicates are.

Comment: This is exactly what i'm looking for. Thank you once again for your regex @Jerry

Comment: @chevalier You're welcome ^^

Answer (score 0):

how about

```
<[^>]+>
```

but this will fail for

```
<item name="drawable/ab_solid>dark_holo">@drawable/frameworks_res_ab_solid_dark_holo</item>
```

where you have a `>` in one of the attributes

Comment: Its only select all the character inside <> including the </item>, and  didn't search & mark the duplicates. Anyway, thanks for the quick reply @gwillie

Comment: Duplicates of what exactly? It is unclear.

Comment: I think its clear enough. Please take a look carefully @hwnd the first string is duplicated '<item name="drawable/ab_solid_dark_holo">'. The question is how to mark this. Thank you

Comment: Yes my question is are you wanting the duplicates of the word `ab_solid_dark_holo` or the whole HTML <item...> string?

Comment: Oh, its for whatever inside the string <item name=".*">

Comment: You mean `<item[^>]*name="[^"]*">`

Comment: Yes, i've tried that similar codes >name="[^"]+" but this doesn't search & mark duplicates.

Comment: but your sample string doesnt contain any duplicates in `name` attribute, if it does show us what you mean by duplicate, because i'm at a loss to see any duplicates

Comment: So sorry for not being clearly at first, but Jerry did awesome job to identify the problem. If any mods willing to edit the question it'll great.